# SH: 1: Syntax error ")" unexpected

Tags: c#, процесс, sh

Вот мой код, который в теории должен запускать скомпилированный .cpp файл

```
 var pc = new Process
                    {
                        StartInfo =
                {
                    Verb = "runas",
                    Arguments = $"./Uploads/{fileName}",
                    FileName = "/bin/sh",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true
                };
pc.Start();
currentSetStatistic.ErrorWhileRunning = pc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
pc.WaitForExit();
```

Но я получаю такую ошибку: **"errorWhileRunning": "./Uploads/Testing: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected\n",**

Мой cpp file

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

И вот где файлы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ошибка в файле sh скрипта `./Uploads/Testing`, к C# коду ваш вопрос не имеет отношения. Кстати, не понял, при чем тут `runas` и Linux

Comment: @aepot сам файл полностью рабочий так как, если я запускаю файл Testing через  терминал все работает

Comment: Если у вас двигатель в машине барахлит, вы в автомастерскую от нее только колесо понесёте со словами "ну я двигатель отдельно от машины заводил - всё работает"? Так вот, если у вас ошибка в шелл-скрипте, почему вы C# код показываете? Еще раз спрошу: `runas` вам зачем?

Comment: Попытаюсь все объяснить, я просто сам не очень понимаю. Приложение  запушено в docker, который на Linux. Когда, я хочу запустить файл через создание процесса в c#, то ошибку выдает, но если через docker консоль, то все работает.

Comment: Это я уже давно понял, а `runas` тут при чем и покажете ли вы скрипт, в котором ошибка?

Comment: У меня кроме этого ничего нет. О каком скрипте идет речь?

Comment: `/Uploads/Testing` об этом, кстати, что содержит переменная `fileName`? Вы смотрели в отладчике? Там точно нет никаких закрывающих скобок? И при чем тут `runas`?

Comment: Там все нормально. runas, если честно не знаю зачем)

Comment: В каком формате скомпилирован файл `Testing`? ELF это, WinPE, что именно? Какая операционка используется для его запуска? `runas` уберите, он для запуска от имени админа под виндой. Права файлу на запуск дали? `chmod +x ./Testing`

Comment: OS/Arch: linux/amd64, тип файла Testing не указанно. Сейчас попробую с chmod +x ./Testing

Comment: Так к чему вся демагогия? Там же написано: `syntax error`. Скобку не поставил `}`. Надо было `var pc = new Process { StartInfo = new {...} };`

Comment: @Aarnihauta разве между `}` и `)` нет разницы?

Comment: @aepot есть, но вполне возможно автор вопроса не в Visual Studio. Студия, конечно же, сразу бы сказала про `}`, а не про `)`. Еще возможно этот синтаксис просто не поддерживается, но я это не утверждаю т.к начал свое изучение с .net 3.1, может на более ранних синтаксис `new Process {}` не поддерживался и надо было обязательно писать `new Process() {}`, но судя по тому, что ваш ответ приняли проблема была вообще не в этом)

Comment: @Aarnihauta говоря про старые версии, вспомните, в какой версии ввели интерполяцию строк и было ли там создание объектов с указанием свойств в `{ }`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую угадать правильный ответ, так как вы не показали примерно ничего, что позволило бы определить источник проблемы наверняка.

```
StartInfo =
{
    FileName = $"./Uploads/{fileName}",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true
};
```